# Function pointer to sort array

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an exercise to implement two function ascendingSort, descendingSort and function *mySort*.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void ascendingSort(int a[], int n) {
     //TODO
}

void descendingSort(int a[], int n) {
    //TODO
}

void mySort(int a[], int n, void (*sort)(int[], int)) {
    /*
     * STUDENT ANSWER
     * TODO: sort array based on sort algorithm of function sort. 
     */
}

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    void (*sortAlgorithm)(int[], int) = descendingSort;
    
    mySort(a, n, sortAlgorithm);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can implement two sort function. But I don't know how to write function *mySort*
Can you give me any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: What are the requirements for `mySort()`? Without specifying that we can't help you here.

Comment: Provided that you have implemented descendingSort and ascendingSort, I think mySort should just call the "sort" function pointer with appropriate arguments.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ function `mySort()` is to decide whether use ascendingSort or descendingSort. You can see in `main()`

Comment: @SvenNilsson, furthermore, the OP does not even need separate function for ascending and descending sort

Comment: @SvenNilsson Yes, but I don't know how to call function pointer in this case :((((

Comment: You don't need to, C++ allows it to be called pretty much like any normal function

Comment: @hidaimrd Just use `sort(a,n);` to call from the function pointer inside `mySort()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but how can I pass value to `void (*sort) (int [], int)` (to sort ascending or descending)

Comment: @hidaimrd You already do this: `void (*sortAlgorithm)(int[], int) = descendingSort;
    
    mySort(a, n, sortAlgorithm);` In that case you've chosen to sort descending.

Comment: @hidaimrd: *"You can see in `main()`"* -- your code does not work as intended, yet you expect us to infer the intent from how the code works??? A much better idea is to use sentences (or perhaps even paragraphs) in your question to describe the intended functionality. The code should be an illustration of your question, not the primary source of information.

Comment: I solved the problem, thank you very much